# Intuition behind expected value formula?

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, expected-value

I just learned the expected value formula for a positive random variable: $E[X] = \int_0^\infty P(X>x)dx$.

I can follow the proof but I'm a little unclear as to what the intuition behind this formula is. Can someone formulate it in a more intuitive manner?

Comment: See what happens in case of a random variable taking positive integer values.

Comment: You are integrating the probability of $X$ being large. The more likely $X$ is to be large, the larger it is on average.